# how to read .docx file in c

Tags: c, docx

I got abstract output which you can not read by running this
code.please tell me,how I can read the output or different method by
which I can read word file in c.I am a beginner and didn't found any detail information about this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  FILE *fr;
  int c;
  fr = fopen("Hello.docx", "r");
  if(fr==NULL)
  {
    printf(" File NOT FOUND!");
  }
  while( c != EOF)
  {
    c= fgetc(fr); /* read from file*/
    printf("%c",c); /*  display on screen*/
  }
  fclose(fr);
  return 0; 
}
```

[image: image is screenshot of output I am getting.]

Comment: What dou you mean by "convert non-readable text into readable one"? It sounds like you want to parse the Microsoft format and "render" the documetn yourself.

Comment: Would only printing the printable character (letters, digits, white space, punctuation...) be enough to satisfy you?

Comment: [Office Open XML (also informally known as OOXML or Microsoft Open XML (MOX)) is a **zipped**, XML-based file format developed by Microsoft for representing spreadsheets, charts, presentations and word processing documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). So step 1 is to unzip the file. Then you need an XML parser.

Comment: I have deleted the line.By that line I was asking how can I read the output because the output i am getting is not readable.

Comment: You might Google libopc

Comment: If you save the document in `.rtf ` format that is text which can be read.

Comment: @Diksha - If you look at the links provided above, you might notice that the [ISO standard for the office file format takes 7000 pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML#ISO/IEC_29500:2008) . Just guess how much code it would take to implement that!

Comment: Thank you @BoPersson .I decided to do it in another language like java

Answer (score 2):

Reading a MS Word document with raw C programming is quite a big project, not suitable for beginners. It is not a pure text file so you can't use `fopen("Hello.docx", "r");`. Rather it is a custom format, so you'd have to open it as binary. Then read the 500+ pages long [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313153(v=office.12).aspx) of the format and treat the data accordingly. Might be worth taking a peek at the Open Office code to get an idea of how much work that's involved.

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly open a word file using fopen( ) as it is difficult to convert a .docx file. Reason being, it is a huge binary file and is compressed, thus while converting it might be possible you don't get the entire data.

Take a look at fseek( ) that might help.